# Custom parent category and subcategory

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories, posts

I really need your help. i just created a WordPress page template that display all the post but my problem is the display of the custom parent taxonomy/category and it's children. My post look like this.

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Parent Category</td>
    <td>Sub Category</td>
    <td>Excerpt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a title</td>
    <td>USA custom category</td>
    <td>Hawaii uder USA</td>
    <td>this is a sample description.</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
```

My only problem is to display the sub category. Anyone can help me?

This is my code on how i display the parent custom category:

```
 <?php

    $term_list = '';
    $terms     = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'origincity' );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, 'origincity' );
        $term_list  .= $parent_term->name ;
    }
    echo $term_list;
   ?>
```

I tried to display the sub category by this code :

```
<?php $terms2 = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'origincity', array("fields" => "all"));

foreach ($terms2 as $term1) {
    echo $term1->name.'<br>';
} ?>
```

but it also return the parent. :(

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to just list the posts? or just the title?

Comment: yes list the post @msbodetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solve the problem by this code:

```
function print_taxonomic_ranks( $terms ){


    // set id variables to 0 for easy check 
    $order_id = $family_id = $subfamily_id = 0;


    // get family
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        if ( $family_id || $order_id != $term->parent )
            continue;
        $family_id = $term->term_id;
        $family    = $term->name;
    }

    // get subfamily
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
        if ( $subfamily_id || $family_id != $term->parent ) 
            continue;
        $subfamily_id = $term->term_id;
        $subfamily    = $term->name;
    }

    // output
    echo "$subfamily";

}
```

Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I dont suggest using your method you are currently using because you don't have enough control over what's showing.

In future use `get_posts();`

It's really simple to use! For example:

```
<ul>
<?php

global $post;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

As you can see you can set how many posts, the category and many more arguments for the posts displayed.

Find out more about the arguments here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts